# Are their any way to save file locally in firebug

Tags: firefox, firebug

Are i can save changes directly to html file i have in my system using firebug. any suggestion to do that in firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no such feature implemented into FireBug, as you are editing the end result and not the actual source.

For example if you'd edit a PHP site with firebug, how would it save?